# Paraview python use offscreen image rendering

Tags: python, paraview

I'm trying to generate images using Paraview in a non-interactive PBS job on a remote linux machine. From the command-line, if I have a file called `cone.py` with the following contents

```
from paraview.simple import *
Cone()
Show()
SaveScreenshot('cone.png')
```

and I type `pvpython cone.py` in the command-line, then a window pops up showing me the image of the cone, and the image is saved. I don't want the window to pop up. It does even if I use `pvbatch cone.py` or `pvbatch cone.py --use-offscreen-rendering`. If I try to run this code from within a PBS job, the image isn't generated (probably because it can't generate the window) and the following error message is generated:

```
ERROR: In /home/kitware/Dashboards/buildbot/paraview-debian4dash-linux-shared-release_qt4_superbuild/source-paraview/VTK/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 542
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x139559c0): bad X server connection. DISPLAY=/var/spool/PBS/mom_priv/jobs/1443323.rrlogin.internal.SC: line 8: 21926 Aborted                 pvbatch cone.py
```

`/home/kitware` isn't a valid directory on my machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the official ParaView binaries for a non-interactive PBS job which doesn't have an accessible X server. You have two options:

1. Check with your site admins to see if there's a way to start up an X server with your job. This would be typically the case if your remote machine has GPUs.
2. Build ParaView from source with OSMesa (which stands for offscreen-Mesa) support. Check out this [wiki page](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/ParaView_And_Mesa_3D) for details. Also refer to this [blog post](https://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/999) if you're building ParaView 5.0 or later with OpenGL2 backend. This will work on systems without an accessible X server.

You cannot use the binaries distributed at paraview.org on X-less systems. `--use-offscreen-rendering` still requires access to an X server to create the OpenGL context unless build with OSMesa support (in which case the command line option is not necessary). If you  are wondering why the command line option then? It's to avoid creating a popup window on X-enabled systems.

Answer (score 3):

If your remote Linux machine has X installed you need to set your DISPLAY variable before running pvbatch. If your remote Linux machine doesn't have X installed you'll need to build with OSMesa (info and directions [here](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/ParaView_And_Mesa_3D)).